# SUMIF for unique entries

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I need to do a SUMIFS statement in Google Sheets but am having a hard time not double counting duplicates in the data. For example:

| Volume | Flavor | Batch # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6000 | CLM | BT1000 |
| 6500 | CLM | BT1000 |
| 7000 | WBG | BT2000 |
| 2000 | CLM | BT3000 |
| 3000 | ISM | BT4000 |
| 5000 | CLM | BT5000 |

I want to SUMIF the volume of all of matching flavors but only add the volume of each Batch # one time. Ideally this would count which ever volume is highest for the associated Batch # So in this instance if did a SUMIF for 'CLM' I would like to get 13500 as the answer.

I tried different variations with QUERY nested inside a SUM statement as well, but couldn't make it work. Open to any approach including using a helper column.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()` with a `group by` clause, like this:

```
=query( 
  query( 
    A1:C, 
    "select B, C, max(A) 
     where B is not null 
     group by B, C", 1 
  ), 
  "select Col1, sum(Col3) 
   group by Col1 
   label sum(Col3) 'Volume' ", 1 
)
```

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).

Comment: Woo hoo! Thanks doubleunary! That worked great.

Comment: In the results of the first cell it returns "sum max " before the number it returns. Is there any way to remove this text from the results?

Comment: Edited the answer to add a `label` clause.

Comment: I tried the new code and it didn't work quite right. I added that and it just overrode the first value and put the label "volume" in that cell. The problem I'm seeing, with the original code, is the first cell of the query returns "sum max 2798" in row 1 of column b. The following results just list the summed up volumes without the "sum max" proceeding it. Having the text stuck in the cell is making it hard for me to plug the data in the rest of the spread sheet.

Comment: If you do not want headers to show, use a `headers` parameter of `0` and a `label` clause with `''`. See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).